# No nodes connecting to host in docker swarm

Tags: docker, docker-swarm

I just followed this tutorial step by step for setting up a docker swarm in EC2 -- https://docs.docker.com/swarm/install-manual/

I created 4 Amazon Servers using the Amazon Linux AMI.

1. manager  + consul
2. manager
3. node1
4. node2

I followed the instructions to start the swarm and everything seems to go ok regarding making the docker instances.

#### Server 1

Running `docker ps` gives:

[image]

The Consul logs show this

```
2016/07/05 20:18:47 [INFO] serf: EventMemberJoin: 729a440e5d0d 172.17.0.2
2016/07/05 20:18:47 [INFO] serf: EventMemberJoin: 729a440e5d0d.dc1 172.17.0.2
2016/07/05 20:18:48 [INFO] raft: Node at 172.17.0.2:8300 [Follower] entering Follower state
2016/07/05 20:18:48 [INFO] consul: adding server 729a440e5d0d (Addr: 172.17.0.2:8300) (DC: dc1)
2016/07/05 20:18:48 [INFO] consul: adding server 729a440e5d0d.dc1 (Addr: 172.17.0.2:8300) (DC: dc1)
2016/07/05 20:18:48 [ERR] agent: failed to sync remote state: No cluster leader
2016/07/05 20:18:49 [WARN] raft: Heartbeat timeout reached, starting election
2016/07/05 20:18:49 [INFO] raft: Node at 172.17.0.2:8300 [Candidate] entering Candidate state
2016/07/05 20:18:49 [INFO] raft: Election won. Tally: 1
2016/07/05 20:18:49 [INFO] raft: Node at 172.17.0.2:8300 [Leader] entering Leader state
2016/07/05 20:18:49 [INFO] consul: cluster leadership acquired
2016/07/05 20:18:49 [INFO] consul: New leader elected: 729a440e5d0d
2016/07/05 20:18:49 [INFO] raft: Disabling EnableSingleNode (bootstrap)
2016/07/05 20:18:49 [INFO] consul: member '729a440e5d0d' joined, marking health alive
2016/07/05 20:18:50 [INFO] agent: Synced service 'consul'
```

I registered each node using the following command with appropriate IP's

```
docker run -d swarm join --advertise=x-x-x-x:2375 consul://x-x-x-x:8500
```

Each of those created a docker instance

#### Node1

Running `docker ps` gives:

[image]

With logs that suggest there's a problem:

```
time="2016-07-05T21:33:50Z" level=info msg="Registering on the discovery service every 1m0s..." addr="172.31.17.35:2375" discovery="consul://172.31.3.233:8500" 
time="2016-07-05T21:36:20Z" level=error msg="cannot set or renew session for ttl, unable to operate on sessions" 
time="2016-07-05T21:37:20Z" level=info msg="Registering on the discovery service every 1m0s..." addr="172.31.17.35:2375" discovery="consul://172.31.3.233:8500" 
time="2016-07-05T21:39:50Z" level=error msg="cannot set or renew session for ttl, unable to operate on sessions" 
time="2016-07-05T21:40:50Z" level=info msg="Registering on the discovery service every 1m0s..." addr="172.31.17.35:2375" discovery="consul://172.31.3.233:8500" 
...
```

And lastly when I get to the last step of trying to get host information like so on my Consul machine,

```
docker -H :4000 info
```

I see no nodes. Lastly when I try the step of running an app, I get the obvious error:

```
[ec2-user@ip-172-31-3-233 ~]$ docker -H :4000 run hello-world
docker: Error response from daemon: No healthy node available in the cluster.
See 'docker run --help'.
[ec2-user@ip-172-31-3-233 ~]$
```

Thanks for any insight on this. I'm still pretty confused by much of the swarm model and not sure where to go from here to diagnose.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like Consul is either not binding to a public IP address, or is not accessible on the public IP due to security group or VPC settings. You are setting the discovery URL to `consul://172.31.3.233:8500` on the Docker nodes, so I would sugest trying to connect to that address from an external IP, either in your browser or via `curl` like this:

```
% curl http://172.31.3.233:8500/ui/dist/
HTML
```

If you cannot connect (connection refused or timeout) then add a TCP port 8500 ingress rule to your AWS VMs, and try again.

Answer (score 0):

After investigating your issue, I see that you forgot open port 2375 for Docker Engine in all four nodes.

Before starting Swarm Manager or Swarm Node, you have to open a TCP Port for Docker Engine, so Swarm will work with Docker Engine via that Port.

With Docker on Ubuntu 14.04, you can open the port by change file `/etc/default/docker` and add `-H tcp://0.0.0.0:2375` to DOCKER_OPTS. For example:

```
DOCKER_OPTS="-H tcp://0.0.0.0:2375 -H unix:///var/run/docker.sock"
```

After that, you restart Docker Engine

```
service docker restart
```

If you are using CentOS, the solution is same, you can read my blog article https://sonnguyen.ws/install-docker-docker-swarm-centos7/

And the other thing, I think that you should install and run Consul in all nodes (4 servers). So your Swarm can work with Consul on its node

Comment: Where do you see that his Docker is not using TCP port 2375 on the nodes? That is what the tutorial asks you to do explicitly. It looks much more likely that the discovery service is not accessible. Also, I would not recommend running Consul on each node, I don't understand what benefit you expect to gain from this. It looks like your example in your blog post does not even use a discovery service or multiple nodes, so this is not relevant to the situation.